# Use Windows Phone maps control without default Bing maps?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, bing-maps

Is there a way to use Microsoft Phone Map Control without the default Bing maps in WP8? I wan't to only display maps from a custom tile source that I have implemented.

Comment: Did you try anything so far?

Comment: I mean that I only wan't to display maps from a custom tile source. The problem is that you can see the Bing maps underneath the custom map. For example when the map is loading, it first displays the Bing maps and the adds the map images from a custom tile source on top of it. I can't find a way to tell the map control NOT to display the Bing maps at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the maps control always includes a Bing maps layer underneath you need to work around this. You can't stop it showing entirely.

How I've done this is the past is to modify the bing tile loading so that it always loads a valid tile, from the Bing maps server, that is a solid color (i.e. From the middle of the ocean or somewhere always covered in snow). This creates a solid background color that the other tiles are loaded on top of. By using the same image for all tiles you only need to download a single file (very small size) and reusing it means it can be cached and reloaded very quickly.